# D Grip vs Barrel Grip Jigsaws

Tags: powertools

I've been looking into getting a new jigsaw and I've noticed that there are two grip types, barrel and D grip. I've looked around and I don't see any good explanation about the differences. Are there any actual advantages of one other the other or is it merely personal preference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its personal preference. Couple things to note:

- With the top grip saw, its more
  natural for me. I look down on the
  cut, where as with a barrel grip I am
  looking to one side.
- The switch placement on a top grip saw is more natural for me as well.  It is usually a trigger under my index finger.  A barrel grip has switch placement on one side.
- Top grip are more wrist action saws so they can be easier (I think) to do more scroll work.

It is mostly personal preference though. I would try would a couple saws.  However, I would bet you would be happy with either.

Answer (score 0):

D grip bosch never let me down. 'Barrel grip' as you put it is more tiring to work with, and I believe they are more for scroll work.